# Detect Disposable Email with Garbage Domain

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing website using php/codeigniter.

I have downloaded a **list of temporary email domains** from github (https://gist.github.com/adamloving/4401361)

I integrated this to my website to filter and validate email address.But I noticed that some domains are garbage and cannot detect by the list provided.

Please image below.

[image]

Currently Im using this code to filter/validate emails:

```
  public function is_temp_mail($mail='')
  {
    $this->db->select('domain');
    $this->db->from('table_disposal_email_domains');
    $domains=$this->db->get()->result();
    foreach($domains as $domain)
    {
      list(,$mail_domain) = explode('@',$mail);
      if(strcasecmp($mail_domain, $domain->domain) == 0){
            return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

How to block garbage domains.Please help.

Comment: Where is the code you tried?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy updated.

Comment: How do you logically determine what is garbage and what is not?

Comment: As shown in the image, you can consider it as garbage disposable domain if it is **random string and not readable**.Unlike other disposable domains like mailinator.com, its readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the issue with disposable emails is that new domains are added daily. So, maintaining your own list isn't gonna be enough after a few days.

You can use the [validator.pizza](https://www.validator.pizza) API, which is free and updated frequently.

Disclaimer: I made this API

Comment: Wow Amazing!. Its really free? Thanks @tompec. Its very helpful. I wish I could have higher limit. :)

Comment: Yes it is :) Contact me on twitter if you want a higher limit @thomaspetracco. Cheers.

Comment: Tried some domains from temp-mail.org and validator.pizza says its not disposable.

Comment: @Tompec You cannot state "it is free", it is misleading. Actually it has both a free and a Pro option, as all validators around.

Comment: @elena We've added a paid plans since that post 4 years ago because some people needed large volumes. But our API is still free to use and requires no signup.

Comment: Excelent service!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simple API for determining the domains of temporary mails, all you need to determine the temporary mail is to send a **GET request**:

```
https://api.testmail.top/domain/check/data=example@mail.com&ip=8.8.8.8
```

with **authorization header**:

```
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX
```

and in response you will receive a message like this if the mail turns out to be **temporary**:

```
{
    "error": 0,
    "result": false,
    "message": "This domain is in Blacklist"
}
```

you will receive such an answer if the mail turns out to be **trusted** (something like gmail.com or yahoo.com):

```
{
    "error": 0,
    "result": true,
    "message": "This domain is in Whitelist"
}
```

I have described error codes and more detailed instructions on this [page](https://testmail.top/en/example)

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you use a third party package to help you on blocking temporary email domains. You can use [MailboxValidator API](https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/plans#api), which had 300 free API credits per month. You can use the free API key with [MailboxValidator CodeIgniter Email Validation Package](https://github.com/MailboxValidator/mailboxvalidator-codeigniter) after sign up.

Disclaimer: I am working at MailboxValidator.